# display alert message after redirect

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a button that executes a function:

```
 $("#btnRemove").click(function () {
            var name= $("#editAccountName").val();

            if (confirm("Are you sure you want to mark " + "''" + name + "''" + " as innactive?")) {
                saveAccount(false);
                window.location.href = "/RxCard/Search";
            }

            alert (name + "was marked innactive.")
        });
```

I need the alert to show after the user is redirected to "/Rxcard/Search"

what do i need to change in my code to get it working like that?

**on a side note, how would do the same but with a CSS customized alert?**
Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by a "customized alert"?

Comment: I mean an alert that i can style with CSS

Comment: You should ask that as a separate question then. However, it is not possible to style browser-level alerts.

Comment: you can not do that. It redirects, that is the end. The alert either needs to before you redirect or the other page needs to know how to show it.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of putting your alert in this code, you need to put it into the script behind `Search` page. Now you can add a url parameter and then in there check it and show the alert if that parameter is set:

```
if (confirm("Are you sure you want to mark " + "''" + name + "''" + " as innactive?")) {
    saveAccount(false);
    window.location.href = "/RxCard/Search?name=" + name;
}
```

And then add this somewhere (doesn't matter that much):

```
$.urlParam = function(name){
var results = new RegExp('[\?&]' + name + '=([^&#]*)').exec(window.location.href);
    if (results==null){
      return null;
    }
    else{
       return results[1] || 0;
    }
}
```

And at last this code goes into your search page code:

```
function() {
    if($.urlParam('name') == true){
         alert (name + "was marked innactive.");
    }
}();
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot run an alert after the `location.href` has changed because it causes the browser to refresh. Once refreshed, your script is no longer running.

You would need to move your alert script into your search page and perhaps pass the name as a querystring arguement.

Answer (score 0):

You could store the name value using localstorage. The value can be evaluated after the redirection so you can display the dialog with the stored value (if any)

You can't style your alert dialog but you can always create a modal dialog from scratch or by using a web framework / library.